# More elegant way to show $X^2+XY+Y^2=Z^3$, if $X=q^3+3pq^2-p^3$, $Y=-3pq(p+q)$, $Z=p^2+pq+q^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I believe I have solved the below problem by just expanding the algebraic terms (I will show this), but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of making the simplification, or if there is something deeper to motivate "why" the terms on the left hand side works in the first place?

The problem statement is:

> Prove the identity
> $$X^2 +XY +Y^2 = Z^3$$
> if $X = q^3 + 3pq^2 - p^3$, $Y = -3pq(p+q)$, and $Z = p^2 + pq +q^2$.

*Proof.*

On the left hand side we have
\begin{align*}
&(q^3 + 3pq^2 - p^3)^2 + (q^3 + 3pq^2 - p^3)(-3p^2q-3pq^2) + (-3p^2q-3pq^2)^2 \\
&=q^6 +6pq^5 - 2p^3q^3 + 9p^2q^4 -6p^4q^2 + p^6 -3p^2q^4  - 9p^3q^3 +3p^5q - 3pq^5-9p^2q^4 +3p^4q^2\\
&\qquad + 9p^4q^2 + 18 p^3q^3 + 9 p^2q^4\\
&= q^6 + 3pq^5 + 6p^2q^4+7p^3q^3 + 6p^4q^2+ 3p^5q+p^6
\end{align*}
The coefficients $1,3,6,7,6,3,1$ make up the fourth row of the trinomial pyramid, so we see that
$$q^6 + 3pq^5 + 6p^2q^4+7p^3q^3 + 6p^4q^2+ 3p^5q+p^6 = Z^3$$
and the desired equality follows.

Comment: in my experience, there isn't really a "deep" reason why this is true. In fact, identities like these get discovered first and then someone somewhere makes use of them somewhere.

Comment: Apply resultant to eliminate $p,q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$  correct in the second edition and almost correct in the3 first. First edition page 49;  correct is
$$ (ax^2 + Bxy+a' C y^2)(a' z^2 + B zw + a C w^2)  =  a a' X^2 + B XY + C Y^2$$  where
$$    X = xz - C yw \; , \; \; \;   Y = axw +a'yz + Byw     $$
This is typed correctly in exercise 3.5, pages 66-67.

For you, $a = a' = B = C = 1.$
$$ (x^2 + xy+ y^2)( z^2 +  zw +  w^2)  =   X^2 +  XY +  Y^2$$  where
$$    X = xz -  yw \; , \; \; \;   Y = xw +yz + yw     $$

To express $(x^2 + xy + y^2)^2, $ take $z=x, w=y$  This gives us
$$  (x^2 + xy + y^2)^2 = X_2^2 + X_2 Y_2 + Y_2^2 $$  with
$$   X_2 = x^2 - y^2 \; , \; \; \;  Y_2 = 2xy + y^2.    $$
Next, compose another (x,y)  by starting over with $z = X_2 = x^2 - y^2$    and $w  = Y_2 = 2xy + y^2. $
We get $X_3, Y_3$   from $    X = xz -  yw \; , \; \; \;   Y = xw +yz + yw     $  so that
$$  (x^2 + xy + y^2)^3  = X_3^2 + X_3 Y_3 + Y_3^2  $$
$$    X_3 = x^3 - 3xy^2 - y^3 \; , \; \; \;   Y_3 = 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2     $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Pages 66-67 in the first edition of Cox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert of [Binary quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form), but inducing the parametrization by scratch might be helpful to understand this "elegant" formalism.

$X^2+XY+Y^2$ is a *quadratic form*. This can be represented by the matrix via
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
X&Y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1/2\\
1/2&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\Y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Thus *diagonalizing* the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1/2\\1/2&1\end{bmatrix}$ gives $A=ODO^T$, where
\begin{equation*}
O=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\1&1
\end{bmatrix},\quad D=\begin{bmatrix}
3/2&0\\0&1/2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
This implies that, via changing $X'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Y)$ and $Y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X-Y)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
\frac{3}{2}X'^2+\frac{1}{2}Y'^2=X^2+XY+Y^2.
\end{equation*}

Now we have
\begin{equation}
3X'^2+Y'^2=2Z^3
\end{equation}
Which, by using the imaginary number, can be decomposed by
\begin{equation}
(\sqrt{3}iX'+Y')(-\sqrt{3}iX'+Y')=2(\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3(-\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3
\end{equation}
when $Z=3u^2+v^2$. Thus, by equating
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3}iX'+Y'&= \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3\\
-\sqrt{3}iX'+Y'&= \sqrt{2}(-\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3
\end{align*}
we get the desired solution. Then
\begin{align*}
X'&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}i}\left((\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3-(-\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3\right)=3\sqrt{2}u(v^2-u^2)\\
Y'&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left((\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3+(-\sqrt{3}iu+v)^3\right) = \sqrt{2}( v^3 - 9 u^2 v)
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
X&=3u(v^2-u^2)+(v^3-9u^2v)=-3 u^3 - 9 u^2 v + 3 u v^2 + v^3\\
Y&=3u(v^2-u^2)-(v^3-9u^2v)=-3 u^3 + 9 u^2 v + 3 u v^2 - v^3
\end{align*}
Now we have $Z=3u^2+v^2$, and want to change this into the form $p^2+pq+q^2$. Using exactly same (diagonalization) method as above, we have the transformation $2u=-p-q$ and $2v=p-q$, we get
\begin{equation}
X=-p^3 + 3 p q^2 + q^3,\quad Y=p^3 + 3 p^2 q - q^3
\end{equation}
Now $X$ and $Z$ are same with above, but $Y$ is not. Why? This happens because there are two (possibly) different solutions in quadratic equation. If we consider the equation above as the following form,
\begin{equation}
Y^2+XY+(X^2-Z^3)=0
\end{equation}
Then the sum of two solutions of $Y$ must be $-X$, due to the *Vieta Formulas*. Hence another solution for $Y$ is
\begin{equation}
\overline{Y}=-X-Y = -3pq(p+q).
\end{equation}

Comment: are you assuming the result ? $Z = X^2+XY+Y^2$ or $Z = 3u^2+v^2$ popped out of nowhere.

Comment: I chose Z=$3u^2+v^2$ since it gives the simplest $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$-element relation.